# Kendo Mvc Multiselect fill values from button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I got a problem with setting the Multiselect Values from Javascript. My Grid looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
            .Name("Test")
            .ValuePrimitive(true)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetValues", "Test").Data("getFilter");
                });
            })
```

Now i try to set the values for the Multiselect from Javascript like this:

```
var multiselect = $("#Test").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
var res = multiselect.value("Test");
```

Now the behaviour is, under the multiselect a "second" multiselect is placed with the value inside. How can the "correct" Multiselect be filled?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I Solved my Problem. For other People might have the same problem, you have to write:

```
var multiselect = $("#Test").data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

instead of:

```
var multiselect = $("#Test").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
```